# COM function fails on VBscript but not VB6 on Win64

Tags: c#, vbscript, com

I have written a COM control in c# .Net 4.5, this COM control uses a 3rd party dll to communicate with a USB device.

On Windows 7 32bit everything works 100% from both VBScript and the VB6 app.  On Windows 7 64bit the VBScript fails when calling the 3rd party dll function that uses the USB device.

The exception is: "System.AccessViolationException" with message: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

What I don't understand is that the same COM control (and the same USB driver) works when instantiated from the VB6 app, but not from the VBScript.

I have looked at the loaded assemblies and registry access using Process Monitor when running the VB6 app and the VBScript but I cannot see anything out of the ordinary.

Any suggestions of what I can troubleshoot or test next?

Comment: vb6 is always 32bit I thought.. as a result running on 64bit or not, its 32bit.

Comment: Yes, unless the *op* actually means VBA.  Even if not, I think this question needs more detail, at least show what has been tried, relevant working example that brings up the issue, the error codes, etc.

Comment: Try to run it as `"c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe" myScript.vbs`

Comment: @MCND I have tested with cscript and wscript from the Syswow64 folder, both yielded the same results, in fact, the script does not even run if not with either of those 2.

Comment: On top of @MCND suggestion are you running them with elevated privileges?

Comment: @Lankymart Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the deal.  Applications written from VB6 are 32-bit. Your application works on 32-bit Windows and from a VB6 app on Windows 64 (which is running as 32-bit, since VB6 produces 32-bits.  So, we know that your DLL works with 32-bit applications.

The thing is, when you run a VB script on Windows 64, it runs as a 64-bit process and you have a mismatch with your 32-bit DLL.  If you run the VB script with the 32-bit version of the VB script engine (c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe or c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe) does it work?  It probably will.

Now, if you compiled your DLL with the AnyCPU processor setting, then you can still register your DLL and get it to work with a 64-bit process.  Just be sure to use the regasm.exe that is in the 64-bit hive.

For example register your DLL as such,

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /tlb /codebase c:\path\to\yourdll.dll
```

Comment: I made a console app that only contains the offending code (that uses the USB device from the 3rd party dll).  This console app is compiled for x86 and it still throws the exception. I have tried compiling the console app for anything from .Net 2.0 and I get the same result.  I get the feeling that VB6 loads some assembly or module that the 3rd party USB driver requires, but comparing the loaded modules from my test app and the VB6 app shows the same modules are loaded.

Comment: You can use Process Monitor to 1) see what file is trying to be loaded or registry entry is being read before the exception is being thrown 2) See what modules or registry entries are being loaded by the VB6 app

Comment: As mentioned in my question, that is exactly what I did when comparing the loaded modules from the VBScript to the VB6 app, they both loaded the same modules from the same location, and accessed the same registry keys.